# How to deal with warning for system.js modules in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using jspm to import angular with es6 module import, vscode shows a warning because it can not find the module angular.

[image]

Is there a way to ignore this warning?

Comment: I've repeated this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462132/vs-code-cant-use-jspm-packages-systemjs-cant-see-angular2-ts-files