# VS Code can't use /jspm_packages; systemjs can't see angular2 ts files

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using JSPM to create a basic Angular 2 workflow. It works (see https://github.com/simonh1000/Angular2-beta-jspm), but I'm not getting intellisense as VS Code does not see the Angular jspm modules, as can be seen in the image. What should I do?

[image: Intellisense can't see jspm modules]

And here is my `tsconfig.json` including the suggestion from Eric:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I can make some progress in VS Code by using this sort of import statement

```
import { Component, View } from '../jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.0/ts/core';
```

But then I get an error when I run it to the effect:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.0/ts/core.js
```

Here is an extract from config.js

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  typescriptOptions: {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "main": "main",
      "defaultExtension": "ts"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Add `moduleResolution: node` in your tsconfig.json under `compilerOptions`.

Comment: may be your VSCode version is old. me too facing same error. and one solution is as mentioned by @EricMartinez

Comment: @EricMartinez i tried the above solution you mentioned but unable to get relove the problem any other solution ?

Comment: That depends. I don't know what your setup is. In Simon's case he's also using an old typescript version (for what I see in tsconfig.json). The ideal would be to use TS 1.7.x.

Comment: OK, so I have TS 1.7 and updated my `tsconfig.json` - see question - but still have not got VS Code working

Comment: @SimonH Did you manage to solve this issue. Because i am still having the same problem. I am also using the latest version of typescript and vscode

Comment: Not really, best I could do is `import { Component, View } from '../jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.0/core'` but that's not future proof

Comment: What i did is install angular2 as a dev dependency with npm. This also did the trick. Hopefully this will be fixed in the future.

Comment: I believe this is because the typescript compiler doesn't know how to resolve modules downloaded through jspm. There's a current issue open for it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6012.

Comment: I wonder why jspm loads npm modules into it's own folder instead of using node_modules...

Answer (score 6):

This is expected at the moment because the TypeScript compiler doesn't know how to "find" JSPM packages.

VSCode relies on the TypeScript compiler, and the compiler only knows to look for modules through NPM packages (e.g. look inside `node_modules/` - that's what `"moduleResolution": "node"` does).

Since you haven't installed Angular 2 via NPM, it's not in the `node_modules/` folder and the compiler doesn't find it. You should get the same error if you were running the `tsc` command-line compiler.

Solutions are [being](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6012) [discussed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039) and it seems TypeScript@next has some basic support to [manually specify](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/blob/master/examples/angular2/tsconfig.json) a list of `paths` to look for modules (I haven't tested it yet). It doesn't seem ideal though as you'll have to manually maintain this list every time your JSPM dependency changes.

An alternative is to install Angular 2 via NPM in addition to JSPM (e.g. `npm install angular2 --save` or `--save-dev`) but that duplicates the dependency and also require manual maintenance when they change.

Such is life at the bleeding edge...

Comment: Would it be possible to `npm install angular2 --save-dev`, instead, for this purpose? But still, I agree, it's less than ideal. A thought I had to minimize the need for synchronization is creating a npm script (or jspm script?) that essentially does a `npm install ${packageName} --save-dev && jspm install npm:${packageName}` (however you would do variable replacement in this scenario; this way, when you run this script, it'll do both for you at the same time.

Comment: Yeah `--save-dev` would also work I think, I updated my answer to mention it. The script would help I guess, but there are other issues such as maintaining all version in sync when you update a dependency, or remove from both NPM and JSPM when you remove one, etc.

Comment: Good point--didn't get far enough along in my thought process to consider updating and removing dependencies--but those are very important development workflow processes. Hence, the need for a more holistic approach, a'la first-class support from TypeScript.

Comment: So, I tried out JSPM 0.17-beta.28 and TypeScript 2.0.2 (2.0 RC) and got it configured correctly such that I now have IntelliSense support in VS Code. It still requires some "path-mapping" in `tsconfig.json`, but it's better than duplicating the installation of Angular 2 between JSPM and NPM.

Comment: It would be neat if jspm could optionally manage those tsconfig mappings for us, since it's the expert in what is being installed where, and the dependencies those paths satisfy.